# problem in table for jasper report

Tags: java

i want to show email address on my report but its too long. if the table column is small the other parts are not seen. so anybody please tell me the solution for this so that the invisible part can all be seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `properties` of `text field`  : 

- `Stretch With Overflow` is **checked**.

- `Stretch Type` of `all text field` is **Relative to Band Height**.